# How to alter all sequence to start with 1 in oracle SQL developer database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to change all the sequence needs to be start with 1 need to reset all the sequence value,
How to alter all sequence to start with 1 in oracle SQL developer database

kindly help

I need script for reset all sequence to start with 1 in oracle SQL developer database.

Comment: Oracle Database and Oracle SQL Developer are two different products (with their own tags). Oracle SQL Developer Database is not a thing.